Efficiently converting real data into String and saving to disk via C++ Mathlink
Consider this minimal-example code:
coords = {{-1., -1., 1.}, {1., -1., 1.}, {1., 1., 1.}, {-1., 1., 
    1.}, {-1., -1., -1.}, {1., -1., -1.}, {1., 1., -1.}, {-1., 
    1., -1.}};
cells = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 1}, {8, 7, 6}, {6, 5, 8}, {7, 3, 2, 6}, {6,
     2, 1, 5}, {8, 5, 1, 4}, {8, 4, 3, 7}};

(* This is for visualization only *)
BoundaryMeshRegion[coords, Thread@Polygon@cells]

lCo = Length@coords;
lCe = Length@cells;

colsep = " ";
rowsep = "\n";
rts[x_] := Riffle[ToString /@ x, colsep];

fileContent = 
  StringJoin[
   StringJoin@Table[{"v ", rts@coords[[i]], rowsep}, {i, lCo}], 
   rowsep, StringJoin@
    Table[{"f ", rts@cells[[j]], rowsep}, {j, lCe}]];

dir = SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Export["tst.txt", fileContent];
file1 = FileNameJoin[{dir, "tst.txt"}];
file2 = FileNameJoin[{dir, "tst.obj"}];
If[FileExistsQ[file2], DeleteFile[file2]];
RenameFile[file1, file2];

It takes point and cells, makes String output from those and saves it to disk, effectively generating an OBJ file.

UPD my mesh uses both triangles and quads.


For big objects, this becomes very, vere slow.
Is there a simple way to utilize Mathlink and C++ code to do the same job much, much faster?
And, what could such a code be?

Have you seen 170884 and the post linked to in one of the answers, 171587?

Ha! I was going to post this very link, too! XD

@C.E. I gave up on setting up boost: no matter the C/C++ Additional Include Directories, it keeps saying "C1083 Cannot open include filel boost/lambda/lambda.hpp" from the "boost getting started" example. Very strange // Windows 10 // Visual Studio 2022.

You can get a speed-up within Mathematica by saving StringJoin to the end:
fileContent = Block[{part1, part2, part3, cellL, cells3, cells4},
  
  cellL = Length /@ cells;

  cells3 = Pick[cells, cellL, 3];

  cells4 = Pick[cells, cellL, 4];

  part1 = 
   Riffle[Riffle[Internal`MRealToString /@ Catenate[coords], " "], 
    "\nv ", 7];

  part2 = 
   Riffle[Riffle[IntegerString /@ Catenate[cells3], " "], "\nf ", 7];

  part3 = 
   Riffle[Riffle[IntegerString /@ Catenate[cells4], " "], "\nf ", 9];
  
  StringJoin@{"v ", part1, "\n\n", "f ", part2, "\n", "f ", part3}
  ];

With random coords and cells with 100,000 rows, it was around 5 times faster on my computer on Mathematica 14.1.
Undocumented function Internal`MRealToString was used which is not guaranteed to be available in the future.

Agree, up to 5 times faster on my computer, the only thing is - my example uses quad cells, and your code generates triangles. Once I change 7 into 9 in part2, it becomes ok. I will update my question. The thing is, my meshes use both triangles and quads. Do you think it's possible to update your otherwise excellent code to handle that?

I've updated the OP. Guess the simplest way to handle triangles/quads would be splitting cells into triples and quads then having part2 and part3 from your approach and finally joining them together.
